# my nuxt-auth token config is correct but token never stored

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

here is my auth config

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "/api/auth/login",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "token"
          },
          logout: { url: "/api/auth/Logout", method: "post" },
          user: {
            url: "/api/user/detail",
            method: "get",
            propertyName: "user"
          }
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenName: "Authorization",
        globalToken: true,
        tokenType: "bearer",
        autoFetchUser: true
      }
    }
  },
```

I checked a hundred times.

I do have a token object return.

```
{token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6I…M2Nn0.Fu5ugLtucxa6cDlD04D5ffQYs4dIKvcqtngJ5J3b5js"}
```

and some reason, My second request doesn't work. I have checked  cause there is no token at the header, I have checked the heard says:

```
Authorization":"bearer undefined
```

that's why my second request doesn't work, no token.

Comment: If you can add complete working code with the error that will help to debug!

Comment: there is no other error, simply say no permission at my second request,  it supposes to get user info, but there is no token at the header.